# iterator for replacing list members in Java?

Tags: java, list, iterator

Hmmm... the Java `Iterator<T>` has a `remove()` method but not a `replace(T replacement)` method.

Is there an efficient way to replace selected items in a List? I can use a for-loop to call get(i) and set(i) which is fine for ArrayList, but would suck for a linked list.

Comment: Why not just remove and insert?

Comment: because java.util.Iterator does not have an insert() method (nor should it)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[`ListIterator.set`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set(E)) as returned by [`List.listIterator()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator()) or [`List.listIterator(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator(int))

(`set` wouldn't make any sense for, say, a `Set` iterator.)

Answer (score 34):

You need a [`ListIterator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) instead of an `Iterator` ([`listIterator()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator()) gives you one). Then use the [`set`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set(E)) method.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [`List.replaceAll(UnaryOperator<E> operator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) since Java 8.

This may be more or less efficient than using a `ListIterator` (which the default implementation does) depending on the type of list that you are using and how many elements you need to replace since it can be overridden to provide better performance but you can't short circuit it and quit part way through (unless you throw an exception).

Some lists (like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`) don't support modification with a `ListIterator` but do support `replaceAll`.

Another advantage is that `replaceAll` will probably be shorter to write with a lambda than using a for loop with an iterator.